# Go back to previous activity after a phone call

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-state-listener

I am using PhoneStateListener to listen for the changes of the mobile call state. What I am working on is to make a phone call after few seconds and then go back to previous activity. However, each time I go back to the activity again, it will run the CallThread again, and I trap into the situation that make a call after a call again and again.
Could anyone please help? Thank you!

This is what I put in onCreate() method of the activity.

```
    Thread CallThread = new Thread(CallRunnable);
    CallThread.start();
```

It will set a runnable to make a phone call.

```
Runnable CallRunable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000); //wait for 5 secs and then make phone call
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        makePhoneCall(phoneNO);

    }
};
```

In my PhoneStateListener,

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            isCalling = true;
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.i("Call", "IDLE");
            if (isCalling) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getIntent());
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isCalling = false;

            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private boolean isCalling = true;
private int mCurrentState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {

if (state != mCurrentState) {    
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.i("Call", "IDLE");
            if (isCalling) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getIntent());
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isCalling = false;

            }
            else {
                isCalling = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    mCurrentState = state;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

of course it will make call again because each time you back from Phone Call IDLE state you, relaunch activity, so it triggered onCreate again,
put an extras parameter there so you can check if it newly create or back from phone call or save to SharedPreference